# Install phpmyadmin on gitlab CE bundle server

Tags: mysql, git, nginx, phpmyadmin, gitlab

I already setup my gitlab CE on my server ubuntu 14.04 VPS (Let assume my domain as `git.domain.com`) and run very well. Gitlab using they own nginx (port 80) and postgresql (port 5432).

I want use the same box for mysql database server. Now mysql are run well on port 3306.

The problem is, if I install phpmyadmin, Where should I tweak so the `git.domain.com/phpmyadmin` can be reacheable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a proxy_pass for that. Assuming you know the port number of the phpmyadmin. Let say port 9000.

Then you can do something like this in your /site-enabled/< app >.conf,

```
server {
  .... where this you listen to port 80, with server git.domain.com
  ...
  location /phpmyadmin/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/$uri;
  }
}
```